# Changing hazelcast configuration at runtime

Tags: caching, hazelcast

Is it possible to change Hazelcast configuration at runtime and if so what parameters are modifiable.

It seems to be possible using [Hazelcast Management Center](http://www.hazelcast.com/products/management-center/) but can't find any examples/references in official docos/forums.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit late to answer your question but better late than never :)

You can modify some of the map config properties after the map has been created using the MapService:

```
HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();

// create map
IMap<String, Integer> myMap = instance.getMap("myMap");

// create a new map config
MapConfig newMapConfig = instance.getConfig().getMapConfig("myMap").setAsyncBackupCount(1);

// submit the new map config to the map service
MapService mapService = (MapService)(((AbstractDistributedObject)instance.getDistributedObject(MapService.SERVICE_NAME, "")).getService());
mapService.getMapServiceContext().getMapContainer("myMap").setMapConfig(newMapConfig);
```

Note that this API is not visible/documented so it might not work in future versions.

We are using this in our application when we need to insert several million entries in a distributed map at startup. Disabling the backup cut the insertion time by 30%. After the data are inserted, we enable the backup.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not impact configuration of near caches and behaviour different within minor versions (eg. 3.4.x). Official reply form hazelcast guys was that dynamic config change is not supported and they won't be investing time in adding such feature (sadpanda).

Answer (score -1):

The Hazelcast internals are not really designed to be modifiable. What do you want to modify?

Comment: Yes, i'd also find it useful to be able to modify max cache size at runtime.

Comment: Can you make a github issue for it so we can track it. 

If you check the code in the com.hazelcast.management package and especially the UpdateMapConfigOperation, then you'll see how it can be done.

I think it would be good to expose this through JMX.